# AdMob integration in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am implementing AdMob in my app. I have added xml codes.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2415896980984028/6183643605" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have added this codes in my activity_main.xml ..Also i have added this code in my MAinActivity class. But when i installed the app in my device for testing it crashed.

```
    adView=(AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.setVisibility(AdView.VISIBLE);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I cannot figure out what is the problem actually.

Comment: Add LogCat output please with crashlog

Comment: Check permissions in manifest + `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` in your layout.

Answer (score 1):

have you added this in manifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

and have you added lib?

Comment: Yes. I did. I have added Lib(Google Play service ) and added those in manifest .

Answer (score 1):

You have to write code in Activity

```
  private AdView adView;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Must ad this line in Menifest.

```
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: @MehediHassan      Did you check logCat?

Comment: @MehediHassan Let do one thing Download source code from here https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/banner  and just put your adUnitId in xml and check what happen.

Comment: @ParagChauhan 
Your solution is wrong because he's using the new admob. You've provided the archaic api. @ Mehedi Hassan, remove the admob sdk jar from your libs folder, do a project clean and check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the admob via the google play service library, add/make the following changes:

In your layout, Change the ad xml namespace from:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"

   -----/>
```

To :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

   ----/>
```

Then in your manifest's application tag, Change:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>
```

to:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Add:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Don't forget the permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Yes I t worked.Thank You .Actually i forgot to add ..
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>